# How to improve my code to get fast result. Basically, I need to calculate business day between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, apply

I have two date column and I need to calculate Business day between them. My data frame contain around 10k rows.
I have written code. To calculate business day but the challenge is it is taking more than 10 minutes to calculate. Is there any fast method?

Below is my code.

```
from datetime import datetime

df_merge['First analysed date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merge['First analysed date'])
df_merge['Requested date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merge['Requested date'])

# Custom business day calendar excluding weekends.
weekmask = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'

#PERSONALIZE Holidays

exclude = [datetime(2023, 4, 4), datetime(2023, 4, 11), datetime(2023, 4, 18), datetime(2023, 4, 19)]

bday_us = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask=weekmask, holidays=exclude)


# Define a function to compute the number of business days between two dates
def num_business_days(row):
    dates = pd.date_range(start=row['First analysed date'], end=row['Requested date'], freq=bday_us)
    return len(dates)

# Apply the function to each row of the dataframe and store the results in a new column
df_merge['Analyze to PRR'] = df_merge.apply(num_business_days, axis=1)
```